# Realm gradle tasks

Tags: android, realm

During my profile report of `assembleDebug` gradle task I discovered two realm related gradle sub-tasks which takes quite big amount of time:

```
assembleDebug - 1m21.44s
- transformClassesWithRealmOptionalAPITransformerForDebug - 22.386s
- transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForIdeDebug - 10.062s
```

**Questions:**

- what exactly those realm related gradle sub tasks do? Can I skip them at some point?
- why they took so long? (22 + 10 = 32 sec)

**Update**

As a workaround I am skipping task via `-x` script parameter

```
assembleDebug -x transformClassesWithRealmOptionalAPITransformerForDebug
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`transformClassesWithRealmOptionalAPITransformerForDebug` is created for removing `RxJava` related APIs since it might create troubles for some cases (cases which need reflection like https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#jackson-databind) which doesn't have the `RxJava` dependency. But we found it doesn't play well in some occasions like https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3033 and https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3022 . So it will be disabled in the next release after `v1.0.1`.

`transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForIdeDebug` is the core part Realm relies on. Basically it replace the field access to the `RealmObject` with Realm accessors by bytecode manipulating. You can see this [post](https://realm.io/news/android-installation-change/) for a bit more details. Thus, this task cannot be skipped.

PS. an [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3034) is created to track the transformer speed improvement.