# Realm is causing extremely slow Gradle builds

Tags: java, android, gradle, realm

so I have recently started using realm (I have just been doing a few basic CRUD examples) and I have found that it causes my build times to go "crazy".

Having a look at a Gradle profile I found the following:

[image]

I normally get a 1-2 minute build time, my PC isn't top of the line but I am working with:

- i7
- 6GB RAM
- SSD

I had a read of this question: [Realm gradle tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928953/realm-gradle-tasks)

I am just wondering if I am doing something very wrong on my end. I have basically just followed along with the "Getting Started" section from Realm's docs: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#getting-started

If there is anything I can add to help figure out what is going don't hesitate to ask.

**Edit**:

I am currently using the work around suggested by the previous post

```
-x transformClassesWithRealmOptionalAPITransformerForDebug
```

I am also using most of the Gradle speed up techniques I could find (Offline mode, increasing heap etc)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is an open Github issue on the matter.  https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3034

Comment: `transformClassesWithRealmOptionalAPITransformerForDebug` task has been removed but not released yet, you can try with our snapshot release.